# Blade Cache in Laravel 5+

Tags: php, laravel, кэширование

При обновлении шаблонов Blade приходится долго ждать изменений  по причине кеширования. Отключать кеширование в php.ini не вариант. Нашел на просторах решение  с прописанем middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;

class ClearCache implements Middleware {

    /**
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $cachedViewsDirectory = app('path.storage').'/framework/views/';
        if ($handle = opendir($cachedViewsDirectory)) {
            while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                if(strstr($entry, '.')) continue;
                @unlink($cachedViewsDirectory . $entry);
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

но при загрузке страницы blade говорит что не нашел последний кеш файл и попросту выбивает ошибку. Есть ли вариант уменьшить время или убрать вовсе.

Comment: а `php artisan cache:clean` не катит, притом в конфиге laravel `app.php` есть опции для кэша

Comment: @Naumov `php artisan cache:clean` знаю про такой вариант но есть ли еще. Вот `app.php` что нужно прописать ?

Comment: @Naumov И именно в `app.php` или `cache.php`,`view.php`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для Laravel 5.0 нужно установить http://packalyst.com/packages/package/kyslik/view-clear
В Laravel 5.1+ уже идёт в комплекте.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class ClearCache implements Middleware {

    /**
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        Artisan::call('view:clear');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: `There are no commands defined in the "view" namespace.`

Comment: там наверное `cache:clear` имееться ввиду

Comment: У меня в laravel 5.1 всё норм отрабатывает. Могу выложить саму команду view::clear.

Comment: @АлександрАндреев `cache:clear` проблема осталась. добавил в `Kernel` если что  в `$middleware`

Comment: @АлександрАндреев даже если так `cache:clear` должна и вьюхи почистить.

Comment: В laravel 5 оказывается нету view::clear. Можно попробовать установить пакет http://packalyst.com/packages/package/kyslik/view-clear